# Escaping URLs for top.location.replace

Tags: javascript, php

I have user input that I am passing to JavaScript `top.location.replace`. E.g.,

```
top.location.replace('USER INPUT URL HERE');
```

I use `strip_tags` on the url, but I feel like it is not enough. What can I do to sanitize user input so it can be properly placed this function call?

Comment: most security concerns make sense when there is an actual threat and that depends on your application use case. In other words, why are you allowing the user to input an url?

Answer (score 0):

To write a PHP string as a JavaScript string, use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
echo 'top.location.replace(' . json_encode($url) . ');';
```

(Note that this adds the JavaScript string quotes automatically.)

If you are writing this to a `<script>` block in HTML rather than a pure JavaScript file, you should also protect against data containing a closing `</script>` . Encoding the `<` character as `\x3C` will do this:

```
echo 'top.location.replace(' . str_replace('<', '\x3C', json_encode($url)) . ');';
```